# Indexing email,phone column in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, varchar

I have a table with above 5 million users with an index for three columns now.

I am updating specific column using email or phone, when am doing this sometimes i have to update 100k users, so to **check with email or phone is taking a while** to check first then get id and **update based on id.**

If I make email and phone  indexed (both should have duplicated values), will my query execute better than now? Is it best to index email and phone as both saved as **Strings** in **Database.**

Comment: This may help you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Strings are not a problem; `TEXT` is.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    INDEX(email),
    INDEX(phone)
)
```

If that hint does not suffice, please provide your current `CREATE TABLE` plus your attempts at SQL for the 'check' and 'update'.

If the question is about testing for *two* columns, here are some tips:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE email = '...'
       OR phone = '...'
```

will be slow.  In general `OR` does not optimize well.

This would be faster:

```
( SELECT id
    WHERE email = '...' )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT id
    WHERE phone = '...' )
```

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` will not work because `email` and `phone` are not unique.

What is the business logic when there are two rows with a matching email?  Do you update both?  What about a email match, but phone mismatch?

If you need *both* to match, then this pair is optimal:

```
UNIQUE(email, phone)

INSERT ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```